# How to use an insert...returning statement as a "table-like" query in jooq?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am writing a SQL query in the form of INSERT INTO ... RETURNING, and then want to aggregate the results.  This is possible with postgres:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS __test;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __test
(
    id    int  not null,
    value text not null
);

WITH things AS (
    INSERT INTO __test
        VALUES (1, 'foo'),
               (2, 'bar'),
               (2, 'baz')
        RETURNING *
)
SELECT id,
       array_agg(value)
FROM things
GROUP BY id;
```

Though I am struggling to find a way to do this with jooq, as an `InsertResultStep` does not implement `Select`, nor does it implement `Table` or `TableLike` interfaces.  Is there a canonical way to achieve this, or should I be looking for a workaround?

```
val insertQuery = DSL
     .insertInto(otherTable)
     .select(
         DSL.select(recordPkColumns)
         .from(recordTable)
         .crossJoin(permValues)
         .where(filter(command.command))
     )
     .onConflictDoNothing()
     .returning()

DSL.select()
    .from(insertQuery) // problem is here!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.11 (and soon 3.12), this is not yet possible in jOOQ without resorting to [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/).

The relevant feature request is here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4474